# Embed a static table with values in a C# program

Tags: c#, .net, lookup-tables

I have an*C# program and want to use an embedded (static/constant) lookup-table in my program. The table has 3 columns: name, value, info and appr. 200 rows with static data.

For some reasons I don't want to use a database table. The methods, which uses the table are called very often so, the access to the table of also often and should be very quickly.

My first idea was, to use a **embeded resource** because it has 3 columns, but the problem is, that the comment-column is not accessable via the ResourceSet entries.

What do you think, which alternatives make sense?

Comment: Normal in-memory collection with struct is not good why?

Comment: Use a static dictionary and make it thread-safe if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

If your data wont ever change. the fastest way is to add them in the code, otherwise you can add them as an embedded resource in lets say csv format, then load them in a static list of struct / class.

For example:

```
public class MyData{

    public static List<MyData> Items;

    static MyData(){
        Items=new List<MyData>();
        // load items to the list
    }

    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
    public string Info {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can access your data anytime you want by using `MyData.Items`